# Countable sub-order $C$ to infinite totally ordered set $T$ such that $\forall t\in T\ :\exists \: c\in C,\:t<c$.

Tags: order-theory

Given any infinite totally ordered set $T$, does there exist a countable subset $C$ such that $C$ is not upper bounded in $T$?

Edit: $T$ also is unbounded from above. My bad for not including this first.

This statement is non-trivial for large $T$, and I don't really have a grasp on how to prove it (my inclination says it is probably true since every simple example that comes to mind satisfies the condition).

Any pointers would be much appreciated. I'm sure this is far simpler than I'm making it out to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the cofinality of $T$, i.e., the smallest cardinality of a cofinal subset of $T$. If $\operatorname{cf}T>\omega$, then every countable subset of $T$ is bounded above; $\omega_1$, the first uncountable ordinal, is the simplest example. If $\operatorname{cf}T=\omega$, let $\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ be a cofinal sequence; clearly $\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$ is a countable subset of $T$ with no upper bound. The only other possibility is that $T$ has a maximum element, in which of course every non-empty subset of $T$ is bounded above, but that possibility is excluded by hypothesis.

Comment: Can you give an example of a set with $\operatorname{cf} T>\omega$?

Comment: @DonThousand: The first uncountable ordinal, $\omega_1$, is the simplest example.

Comment: Is there any simple proof of $\omega_1$ having this property? A link or sketch would be much appreciated. Sorry for the questions, I just want some perspective.

Comment: @DonThousand: You need to know a little about ordinals, in particular, that each is the set of smaller ordinals. The crucial point here is that $\omega_1$ is the **smallest** uncountable ordinal. Thus, if $C$ is a countable subset, each $\alpha\in C$ has only countably many predecessors, so there are only countably many ordinals that are less than some member of $C$. But $\omega_1$ is uncountable, so it must have a member that is not in $C$ and not less than any member of $C$ and therefore is an upper bound for $C$.

Comment: Ah, right, since each element of $\omega_1$ is countable. What a nice example!