# Increasing sequence whose supremum is $x\in X$

Tags: set-theory

Let $X$ be an ordered set. Let $x$ be a point in $X$ without an immediate predecessor. That is, there does not exist a point $a<x$ in $X$ such that $(a, x)=\emptyset$.

Prove that there exists an increasing sequence in $X$ whose supremum is $x$.

**Edit:** Seems like this is untrue if there is no stricter condition on $X$. Then what if $X$ is only *countably infinite*? If the claim is true for a countably infinite $X$, can one explicitly construct such a sequence?

*As for this, I've tried to construct a sequence based on a bijection $f:\mathbb{Z}_+\to \{a\in X\,|\, a<x\}$, but failed to construct one whose supremum is exactly $x$.*

Comment: I don't think this will work if you demand a *sequence,* since if $X$ is too infinite than a countable object might not be able to reach $x.$

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016901/countable-sub-order-c-to-infinite-totally-ordered-set-t-such-that-forall-t) is a duplicate, as it disproves your claim.

Comment: Sequence can be used to mean a well ordered set, not just one isomorphic to $\Bbb N$. Maybe that is the meaning here.